# I Can't GroupBy arrays using computed in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

i want help on this. Thank you.

I have an object :

```
Funding : [
{person_id:'1';
Amount : '100'},

{person_id:'1';
Amount : '200'},

{person_id:'2';
Amount : '150'},
```

I would like to groupBy Funding by person_id and get the sum of Amount in each group. 
I use this code but nt working ..

```
  Groupe(array,key) {
      const result = {}
      array.forEach(funding => {
      if (!result[funding[person_id]]){
      result[funding[person_id]] = []
      }
      result[funding[person_id]].push(item)
       })
      return result
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created two different examples, one a function will return the summed amount of just one of the keys. In the second, it will return the summed amount of all the keys.

Here is a codepen for that https://codepen.io/aquilesb/pen/BvbqMd

```js
const data = [
{
  person_id:'1',
  amount : '100'},

{
  person_id:'2',
  amount : '150'
},
 {
  person_id:'1',
  amount : '150'
},
{
  person_id:'2',
  amount : '70'
}
];

const personID = '1';

// return by a key
const groupByKey = (list, key) => list.reduce((acc, item) => {
  if (item.person_id === key) {
    return parseInt(item.amount, 10) + acc;
  } 
  return acc;
}, 0);

//return the sum of all keys
const groupAll = list => list.reduce((acc, item) => {
  const accAmout = acc[item.person_id] || 0;
  return Object.assign({}, acc, {[item.person_id]: accAmout + parseInt(item.amount, 10)});
}, {});

console.log("groupByKey", groupByKey(data, personID));
console.log("groupAll", groupAll(data));
```

Comment: Thank you it working, but i can't merge results to vuejs objects. i tried 
this.results = groupbyKey;  isn't working !

Comment: I create a codepen to show you how to use it: https://codepen.io/aquilesb/pen/wRZMxw

Answer (score 0):

You can use lodash's [*.groupBy*](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#groupBy) function and [.reduce](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#reduce) functions to group by Person ID first, and then add the amounts together. Using a computed property in Vue makes this very easy, and you can access the object in your template like its a regular property.

#### Vue/HTML Template

```html
<div id="app">
  <ul v-for="(total,personId) in fundingByPerson">
    <li>Persond ID: {{personId}}, Amount : ${{total.toFixed(2)}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

#### Javascript

```js
// Include lodash via `npm install lodash`
import _ from 'lodash';

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      Funding: [
        {person_id:'1', Amount : '130'},
        {person_id:'1', Amount : '200'},
        {person_id:'2', Amount : '350'},
        {person_id:'45', Amount : '150'}
      ]
    }
  },
  computed: {
    // Group by Person, then add amounts together
    fundingByPerson: function(){
        let byPerson = _.groupBy(this.Funding, 'person_id');
        let totals = {};
        // Loop over each Group of Amounts, indexed by personId
        _.forEach(byPerson, function(amounts, personId){
            totals[personId] = _.reduce( byPerson[personId], function(sum, entry){
            return sum + parseFloat( entry.Amount );
        }, 0);

      })
      return totals;
    } // fundingByPerson
})
```

Here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mdy59c7e/6/

Comment: Thank you for your interest. In my case isn't working, maybe cuz i have a more complicated objet ? i dont have only person_id and amount  .. ? I tried to debug, i have this error : "(error during evaluation)" , also i removed the sum function and still not working, the error is comming from byPerson

Comment: I apologize I wasn't clear. You need to install lodash and include it in the file. Let me edit my answer to clarify

Comment: can i insert grouby second argument as array?

Comment: @Franz I believe you can either group by an item key (as a string) or pass an "iteratee" function that will return a value based on that function. https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#groupBy